# can this value be output with inline code in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Please consider the following inline code:

```
string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers.ToArray())
```

If the Headers structure above were a `Dictionary(string, string)`, the code above would output the following:

```
[MyHeaderKey1, MyHeaderVal1],[MyHeaderKey2, MyHeaderVal2]
```

However, the `Dictionary` value is a `string[]` so the following gets output instead:

```
[MyHeaderKey1, System.String[]],[MyHeaderKey2, System.String[]]
```

I need to be able to generate output like the first code example but against the `Dictionary` with the `string[]` value.  It's ok if I only take the first item of the `Dictionary` - `string[]` value. Can this be done with inline C#?

Comment: Can you give an example? How would the `string[]` be formatted? by joining the individual strings with ","?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use Linq `Select`.

```
string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers.Select(x => string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", x.Key, FormatThisArray(x.Value))))
```

**EDIT**: Since OP mentioned that the value is `string[]`, the default `x.Value` as described above may not produced desired output. I'm not sure how OP would format the value of the dictionary item and assuming `FormatThisArray` is a function that formats the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
var result =
    string.Join(",",
        context.Request.Headers.Select(x =>
            string.Format(
                "[{0},{1}]",
                x.Key,
                "(" + string.Join(",", x.Value) + ")")));
```

This joins the individual items inside each `string[]` with a `,` and puts them between brackets.

Output would look like this:

```
[MyHeaderKey1,(v1,v2,v3)],[MyHeaderKey2,(v4,v5,v6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the fist value:

```
string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers.Select(d=>new {d.Key,Value=d.Value.FirstOrDefault()}));
```